# try server connection by evaluating server reply

Tags: c#

I am makeing a program in C# which needs to have a connection with a server.
I'm building it with redundancy in order to eliminate server faults.
Due to this, I'm having a textfile with server addresses which looks like this:

```
2011-09-21 18:01
http://server1.server.com
http://server2.server.com
http://server3.server.com
```

The date is there to make sure the program has a fresh list of servers.
The first thing it does when it starts, is to download this list and compare the date.
If the downloaded file has a newer date, it replaces the older files.

What I wan't to happen now, is that I want the program to read the file and make a list of possible servers (this is already done), and then iterate through the list to find a server that is giving the reply the server is expecting.

Once the reply is gotten, it should stop checking and set the variable "server" to the server that just responded correctly.

I have been trying with the following procedures, without any luck:

```
int srvs = servers.Count();
int i = 0;
string response = string.Empty;
while (i < srvs)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    try
    {
        response = client.DownloadString(servers[i] + "testcon.php");
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if (response == "OK")
        {
            server = servers[i];
        }
    }
    if (servers.Contains(server))
        break;
    i++;
}
```

This didn't work, it didn't stop the loop until it was at the end of the list.
Next thing I tried, was this:

```
var client = new WebClient();
foreach (string s in servers)
{
    try
    {
        response = client.DownloadString(s + "testcon.php");
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
    if (response == "OK")
        server = s;
    }
        break;
    }
```

How should I do to make it stop and set the server to the first server that is responding as expected (currently with "OK").

Comment: out of morbid curiosity, why not use a clustering option or DNS round-robin?

Comment: Because of two reasons: 1. I don't know how to set up a cluster, except for actually purchasing two clustered VPS/root servers. and 2: I don't know how to set up a DNS round-robin. The servers I am using are plased on different locations in the world, and I get them for free since I know the server owners.  Although for the last question/answer.. this is something I will look up. :)

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
int srvs = servers.Count();
int i = 0;
string response = string.Empty;
while (i < srvs)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    try
    {
        response = client.DownloadString(servers[i] + "testcon.php");
        if (response == "OK")
        {
            server = servers[i];.
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
    }
    i++;
}
```

or this:

```
var client = new WebClient();
foreach (string s in servers)
{
    try
    {
        response = client.DownloadString(s + "testcon.php");
        if (response == "OK")
        {
            server = s;
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I tried exactly this first, but then I get this message: Error 9 Control cannot leave the body of a finally clause

Comment: Why place this in a finally block? Either place your evaluation right after your request, or put a 'continue' in your catch block and your evaluation after your try-catch structure. Both options means skipping the finally.